# How do i stop a div from inheriting the CSS class from its parent div?

Tags: html, css, magento

i know there is a lot of questions on the subject but i cant get the solutions to work.
I created a CSS class called 'color-shift' that shifts any thing with colour through the hue, I created it so that the header logo and text can cycle through colours. But now i want to add a black background with some coloured lines that change colour using the CSS class. the problem is, is that the background is applied to the div class 'wrapper'. This div contains the whole page, so everything changes colour. I somehow want to exclude the 'color-shift' class from the main container, so that only the background changes colour.

Any help would be appreciated. (P.S. I'm using Magento 1.9, if you need to know that).

Here is the relevant html and css:

```css
.wrapper {
    min-width: 320px;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(/media/mountains-min.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}

.color-shift {
    -webkit-animation: hue 15s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper color-shift">
    <div class="page">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got two options.
1. You will need to overide that class in your css style sheet.

example:

```
.color-shift {
    -webkit-animation: hue 15s infinite linear;
}

.page {
      -webkit-animation: none;
      color:black;
}
```

add it below so it override the previous one.

2. Make a div only with that class.

Example:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="color-shift></div>
    <div class="page">
    </div>
</div>
```